# Changing the alpha with ColorTransform (tint + alpha)?

Tags: actionscript-3, colors

I am trying to change the alpha of a tint using the ColorTransform class, is it possible to do this?

```
private function setColor(target:DisplayObject, color:uint, alpha:uint = 150) {
            var colorTransform = new ColorTransform();
            colorTransform.color = color;
            colorTransform.alphaOffset = alpha;
            target.transform.colorTransform = colorTransform;
        }
```

However, when I try to use it with say,

```
setColor(this, 0x333333, 100);
```

I seem to get a solid dark grey instead of a partially transparent tint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use alpha alphaMultiplier instead of alphaOffset. When you use alphaOffset, it add alpha, so if alpha is already at 100% you won't see any transparency.

Comment: okay but do I have to pass it in as a 0xff value? How does that work for alpha?

Comment: No, it's a multiplier, so if you want 50%, you set alphaMultiplier  to 0.5